Installing the latest GCC and Clang from WinLib causes a missing dll error
I found that for some strange reason, installing the latest WinLib binaries causes clang to not work (version "GCC 14.1.0 (with POSIX threads) + LLVM/Clang/LLD/LLDB 18.1.5 + MinGW-w64 11.0.1 (UCRT) - release 1   (LATEST)").
Running clang --version results in the git bash terminal returning blank and after a few moments, rerunning the command results in the error: error while loading shared libraries: libLLVMX86Desc.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. Upon looking in the bin directory I can see that running the command strangely deletes the libLLVMX86Desc.dll file which then causes the error when running the command afterwards.
I've checked with the binaries from the last version (version "GCC 13.2.0 (with POSIX threads) + LLVM/Clang/LLD/LLDB 18.1.5 + MinGW-w64 11.0.1 (UCRT) - release 8") and this seems to work fine. What could be the issue? I've tested this on another machine and no bugs appear to be happening with either version on that one.

Sounds like something is simply off with the particular build from Winlibs. Would probably be best to poke the guy providing these directly, though he's active on SO too so maybe he'll spot this.

I've met the same issue today.
Windows Security marked libLLVMX86Desc.dll a Trojan, it might have caused the file to be deleted.
However, I am not sure whether the libLLVMX86Desc.dll is safe or not.
Windows Security TrojanDetected

I would download an older version that doesn't require the missing .dlls but I'm probably stating the obvious.

@Akiu yes thank you this was indeed the issue. I ended up just trusting the dlls and adding the folder as an exception to windows defender

Yes, there have been issues with Microsoft Defender and also some other antivirus software falsely detecting LLVM binaries in https://winlibs.com/ releases as viruses.
This was reported to Microsoft and has been resolved.
